# Number Theory Transform recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, fft

I was studying the Fast Fourier transform and Number theory Transform, I fully understood the FFT recursive code, I need NTT code to work with, but everywhere I see, its iterative code, but for learning purpose I need the recursive code of it.

Comment: For learning purpose it is best, you try it yourself. Hint: the transformation is very similar to the FFT.

Comment: NTT is exactly the same as FFT, except that the element type is an integer instead of a complex, and you do modulus math.  You should probably convert the FFT code you already understand.  If you paste it in or link to it, someone may help with any parts you find difficult.

Comment: OK thanks I try then

Comment: The difficult part was that, I also want my code to calculate the inverse ntt with a boolean flag, this was the main difficulty to me